# How to resolve a wildcard filespec using Java 7

Tags: java, wildcard

I've searched, but can't seem to figure out how to write java code that takes as input a String containing a wildcard (asterisk), and outputs a String with the wildcard resolved.

I have a special situation where I know there is either 1 or 0 matching filespecs, so I'd like to have the returned String either be a valid filespec, or null.

I've gotten some example code to work using Files.walkFileTree(), but it doesn't do exactly what I want. I want to get the resollved filename back as a String that I can use in subsequent code...

I simply want to pass some code a String filename that includes an asterisk

```
e.g.: input this String:   filename*.tr
```

and get back a String with the asterisk resolved to the 1st matching filename (or null):

```
e.g.: get back this String:  filename_201402041230.tr
```

The directory where these files reside contains several thousand files, so iterating over all files in the directory and parsing the names myself isn't an attractive option.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Apologize for the outburst... Thanks for the tip... Here's what I was trying before:
However, as I said this isn't what I want, but it's as close as I could get from my RESEARCH.

```
Path startDir = Paths.get("C:\\huge_dir");                                         
String pattern = "filename*.tr";                                                   

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();                                          
final PathMatcher matcher = fs.getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);                  

FileVisitor<Path> matcherVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()                   
 {                                                                                 
 @Override public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attribs)
  {                                                                                
  Path name = file.getFileName();                                                  
  if (matcher.matches(name))                                                       
    System.out.println(file);                                                      
  return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;                                                
  }                                                                                
 };                                                                                
try                                                                                
  {                                                                                
  Files.walkFileTree(startDir, matcherVisitor);                                    
  }                                                                                
catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

Comment: Add your sample code so people can see what you have tried and where you are going wrong.  I didn't downvote this, but I think someone else probably did because it sounds like you typed your homework assignment in here.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to show my current code since it's kind of a wild goose chase since it's not doing what I want, it's merely println-ing all files that match, instead of returning a String that I can use later in my logic.

Comment: However, in case it's useful, here it is:

Comment: I give up, I can't get code to format in a readable manner in a comment... reading the help was not helpful.

Comment: Don't post code in a comment, you can just edit your question (there's a link under the tags) to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nio2 [`Files.newDirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String%29) method with an additional pattern matcher to only list files which match the pattern. As your string already is a `glob` pattern, you can just pass it as the second argument:

```
String pattern = "filename*.tr"
try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, pattern)) {
    //iterate over all matching files
    List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Path path : ds) {
        paths.add(path);
    }
    if (paths.isEmpty()) {
        //no file found
    } else if (paths.size() == 1) {
        //found one result
        Path result = paths.get(0) //now do whatever
    } else {
        //more than one match - probably an error in your case?
    }
}
```

Comment: @RacerNerd there's no indication that this is homework, and as it's not as easy to get right (there's too many tutorials for java6 and below so you have to know to search for either nio2 or the specific classes) I thought I'd answer it. Also, OP mentions trying `Files.walkFileTree` which I count as an attempt, although it's not that useful in this case.

Comment: @user3380152 please refrain from posting unconstructive comments. Simply ignore the guy and everybody wins. Also, if this answer was helpful you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) with the check mark under the downvote button.

Comment: BTW: for the code you posted, I'm getting an "incompatible types" error for ds on the "for" loop line.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments, every time I hit enter for a comment newline it adds the comment.  I've lurked here for years, but obviously new to posting here...  it's been a great resource for me many times.

Comment: @user3380152 I forgot the generics on the DirectoryStream; it should work with them included. Regarding the comments, you can edit comments for 5 minutes after posting, and you can always delete them.

Comment: More good tips. Thanks again for providing helpful and constructive assistance!

Comment: One more correction, I had to change paths.append() to paths.add(), now working like a champ. Thanks again!